# Override "Display select options" to see them in reversed alphabetical order

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Can anyone advise me how to override the [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module to display select options in reverse alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1):

there seems to be a patch to change the sort order: http://drupal.org/node/466828#comment-4904174